# How do I open a database in ItemListFragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I always created Lists in android but I am new to Fragments. I have a database called ItemListAdapter and it has a constructor ItemListAdapter(Context ctx). Now after inserting the items I want to display them and I am using the masterDetail View in android and it has fragments. How do I display the list here. I see in ItemListFragment class which implements ListFragment there is a TODO that  says // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
My Questions is how do I call the database here. during initialization i am not able to pass the context ItemListAdapter(this) gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment you can use the getActivity() function to return a context. So what I have found to be the easiest way to complete this is to create a context variable and assign the variable to getActivity(). If someone has a better way of doing this I am all ears as I too had this problem. Example:

```
public Context context;

// where you will open your database
context = getActivity();
mDbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
```